# Как импортировать значение константы в другой файл node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот контроллер, метод которого проверяет статус на true/false, мне нужно значение const {stat} передать в другой файл.

```
async function getStat(req, res) {
      const {stat} = req.body;
      try {
        if (typeCheck('Undefined', stat)) {
          res.json({success: false, message: 'err'});
          return;
        }

        if (stat !== 'true' && stat !== 'false') {
          res.json({success: false, message: 'err'});
          return;
        }

        gameEmitter.emit('getStat', {
          Status: stat, callback: (err) => {
            if (err) {
              res.json({success: false, message: err});
              return;
            }
            console.log(stat);
            res.json({success: true, message: 'status ' + stat});
            return stat;
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        winston.error(`stat - ${e}`);
        res.json({success: false, message: 'error'});
        return stat;
      }
      resolvePromise(stat);
      return stat;
    }
```

передать нужно вот в эту функцию:

```
async function checkMessage() {
    let out = await controller.getStat(req, res);
    console.log(out);
}
```

Почему-то выводится undefined либо [AsyncFunction: getStat]

Comment: Не силен с ***NODEJS***, но что-то мне подсказывает, что надо экспортировать эту самую константу,  а в том файле к котором  сама функция `checkMessage`  эту самую константу запросить...

Comment: @Air если вы про const controller = require('../controller'); то у меня так и стоит в начале файла

Comment: Ну этого нет в примере, я и подумал грешным делом...))

Comment: А как попадают req, res   в функцию checkMessage?

Comment: @Дмытрык post роутинг

Comment: Я не в курсе, что это такое, код бы увидеть

Comment: @Дмытрык router.post('/getStat/set', authMiddleware, rolesMiddleware('user'), messagesController.getStat);

Comment: А при чем тут, тогда checkMessage? Где в приведенном коде, она используется? У Вас какой-то секрет5ый код, что Вы его порциями выдаете? Не факт, что я могу помочь в решении проблемы, но Вы не даете даже шанса

Comment: @Дмытрык мне в checkMessage нужно передать значение const {stat} из getStat, у меня checkMessage не принимает никаких параметров на данный момент

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере добавьте внизу следующую строчку
`exports.getStat = getStat;`

А в нужном файле используйте
`const getStat = require('путь к файлу');`

Теперь вы можете использовать функцию getStat в нужном вам файле.

Пример: `const stat = await getStat(req, res);`